# Alternative to Ria Services

Tags: web-services, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, devforce

Hi I'm looking for another approach than use Ria Services with silverlight.
We are using Silverlight 4 and .NET 4.0

Have someone make any nice solution with shared assemblies (maybe linked files so domain logic are spread). And maybe any nice framwork to make communicating with the wcf services in a clean way?? It would be really nice if it could support preservereferences :)

I'm looking for links and blogs.

I prefer to not use Ria Services cause its Data Driven mind with need to implemmenting ID's everywhere and lack of support for value objects. I'll also using MVVM so all the logic to undo, notify and so on isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at DevForce by IdeaBlade ( http://www.ideablade.com/ ).

The DevForce product has been around for a number of years and definitely has MVVM support. I looked at it for a project recently and I found the team very helpful. There is an evaluation light edition so you can try before you commit to a purchase.

Comment: Well I have looked at ideblade even if feels like an good 3d part. I want to minimize third part software, and its to integrated with EF we are using NHibernate (can it be used with NHibernate??).
I have only seen screencast and I'm kind of allergic to create my domainmodel from the database, we work the other way around, domainmodel first then database. But I haven't really evaluated ideblade.com so I can be wrong on these assumptions.